# Your app was given a scene with session role UISceneSessionRole(_rawValue: UIWindowSceneSessionRoleVolumetricApplication) error

Tags: swiftui, visionos

I am developing for visionOS and I am getting the following error when trying to run my app:

`Your app was given a scene with session role UISceneSessionRole(_rawValue: UIWindowSceneSessionRoleVolumetricApplication) but no scenes declared in your App body match this role.`

App.swift:

```swift
@main
struct Day008App: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }

        ImmersiveSpace(id: "ImmersiveSpace") {
            ImmersiveView()
        }

    }
}
```

ContentView.swift:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var showImmersiveSpace = false

    @Environment(\.openImmersiveSpace) var openImmersiveSpace
    @Environment(\.dismissImmersiveSpace) var dismissImmersiveSpace

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Toggle("Show ImmersiveSpace", isOn: $showImmersiveSpace)
                    .toggleStyle(.button)
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: showImmersiveSpace) { _, newValue in
            Task {
                if newValue {
                    await openImmersiveSpace(id: "ImmersiveSpace")
                } else {
                    await dismissImmersiveSpace()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

ImmersiveView.swift

```swift
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import RealityKitContent

struct ImmersiveView: View {

    @State var model = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            content.add(model.setupContentEntity())
        }
        .gesture(
            SpatialTapGesture(count: 2)
                .targetedToAnyEntity()
                .onEnded { value in
                    model.addAxis(value: value)
                }
        )
    }
}

#Preview {
    ImmersiveView()
        .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I created my project, I had set the Initial Scene to "Volume":

[image]

Apparently, this adds the following lines to `Info.plist`:

```
<key>UIApplicationPreferredDefaultSceneSessionRole</key><string>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleVolumetricApplication</string>
```

Removing these lines fixed the issue.

---

Alternatively, you can set the `Preferred default scene session role` to a value that is appropriate for your app.

[image]